# Weinberg's proof that $F^{\alpha \beta}$ is a tensor

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, tensor-calculus

I am interested in Weinberg's approach to proving that $F^{\alpha \beta}$ is a tensor in his book Gravitation and Cosmology. He begins by rewritting the Maxwell equations as:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\alpha}}F^{\alpha \beta} = -J^{\beta}$$
and
$$\epsilon^{\alpha \beta \gamma \delta}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\beta}}F_{\gamma\delta} = 0$$
He thens conludes that $F^{\alpha \beta}$ is a tensor, that is
$$\tag{1}F^{'\alpha \beta} = \Lambda^{\alpha}_{\gamma}\Lambda^{\beta}_{\delta}F^{\gamma \delta}$$
since $J^{\alpha}$ is a four vector and because if $F^{\alpha \beta}$ is a solution to the two Maxwells equations then so is (1) in a Lorentz-transformed coordinate system.

My struggle is that this seems slightly backwards to what I know. If a tensor satisfies an equation in one refrence frame then it will also be true for any other transformed frame, can I run this backwards though? If a quantity is true in one refrence frame and any transformed frame then it must be a tensor?

Comment: Can you clarify where the problem is in your last paragraph a little more? I think the statement is that since $J^\beta$ is a tensor of rank $(1,0)$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\alpha}$ is a tensor of rank $(0,1)$. We know how both of them transform (contravariant and covariantly), so if you transform it to $\frac{\partial}{\partial x'^\alpha}F'^{\alpha\beta}=-J'^\beta$ you recover the required result. So your last sentence is kind of like saying "It is a tensor in one frame and it transforms to other frames as a tensor"

Comment: Yes, I think I understand. If we do a lorentz transform and require that the equation remain the same(not sure if this is an einstein postulate or a tensor thing) we have $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{'\alpha}} F^{' \alpha \beta} = -J^{' \beta}$. So that $\Lambda_{\alpha}^{\gamma} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\gamma}} F^{' \alpha \beta} = \Lambda^{\beta}_{\delta}J^{\delta}$ iff $F^{' \alpha \beta} = \Lambda^{\alpha}_{\gamma} \Lambda^{\beta}_{\delta} F^{\gamma \delta}$. Is this the line of reasoning?

Comment: In regards to my einstein or tensor question, I could be wrong but I think they are the same thing. We use tensors precisely for the reason that they do what the einstien postulate wants,that is the equations take the same form in a any lorentz frame. Is this correct?

Comment: If by "Einstein postulate" you mean the postulates of special relativity (that the laws of physics are equivalent in every inertial frame), then yes, they are equivalent assuming we are working in flat spacetime with Lorentz transforms.

Comment: If we look at a classical analog, the inertia tensor, which is defined by $I=\mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{I}\cdot\mathbf{n}$ where $I$ is a scalar and $\mathbf{n}$ are vectors and let's say we are looking at rotations $\mathcal{R}$. $I$ is a scalar and doesn't change when rotated, but $\mathbf{n}$ goes to $\mathbf{n}'$ so from this for $I$ to be invariant we must have that $\mathbf{I}'=\mathcal{R}\mathbf{I}\mathcal{R}^{-1}$. Thus if $\mathbf{I}$ satisfies these requirements (i.e., that it is defined by$I=\mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{I}\cdot\mathbf{n}$), ...

Comment: then it is a tensor by definition because it is constructed from vectors which transform as vectors and as such it transforms as (loosely speaking) a "_product of vectors_" or rather, it transforms as a tensor.

Comment: I think I understand, thank you.